# one point compactification of uncountable set (discrete space) is not metrizable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$X=\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable set. 
$(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{D})$ is locally compact and Hausdorff space, where $\mathcal{D}$ is discrete topology. Then there exists one-point compactification $(\mathbb{R}_\infty, \mathcal{D_\infty})$ here $\mathbb{R}_\infty=\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ and $\mathcal{D_\infty}=\mathcal{D}\cup \{\mathbb{R}_\infty-K | K {\rm\; is\; finite\;set}\}$. This space is compact Hausdorff space. And I'm sure this space  $(\mathbb{R}_\infty, \mathcal{D_\infty})$ is "not" metrizable. But I can not prove this. Help me.

Comment: If it were metrizable, then it would have a dense countable subset, but this is not possible since this would imply that $(\mathbb{R} , \mathcal{D})$ has a dense countable set.

Comment: Alternatively, the compactification fails to be first countable at $\infty$, so it cannot be metrizable.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons: metrisable spaces are first countable and $\mathbb{R}_\infty$ is not, at $\infty$. Suppose $\infty$ has a countable local base $U_n$, all of the form $\mathbb{R}_\infty - K_n$ where $K_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Then $\cup_n K_n$ is a countable subset of the reals, which is an uncountable set, so we have some $p \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \cup_n K_n$. But then $\mathbb{R}_\infty \setminus \{p\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $\infty$ and if $U_n = \mathbb{R}_\infty \setminus K_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}_\infty \setminus \{p\}$, it would, imply that $p \in K_n$, which it is not. So this open neighbourhood of $\infty$ does not contain a member of the local base. So a local base of $\infty$ cannot be countable.

Second: A compact metrisable set is separable. But any dense subset of $\mathbb{R}_\infty$ must intersect all isolated points $\{x\}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so is at least as large as the reals. So it is not metrisable.